# Android AutoValue Inheritance

Tags: java, android, inheritance, auto-value

I'm having a hard time using the inheritance on `AutoValue`. I have an API which gives the details of a transaction. Some of the fields are present on all types of transactions, but the details are not. Details is specific for each type of transaction.

**transaction type 1 json response**:

```
{
   "status": "Processing",
   "date": "2018-24-1",
   "specific_1": "abc",
   "specific_2": "xyz"
}
```

**transaction type 2 json response**:

```
{
   "status": "Cancelled",
   "date": "2018-23-1",
   "specific_3": "def",
   "specific_4": "ghi"
}
```

Without `AutoValue`, I'll just have to create a `Parent Class` that has `status` and `date`and extend it to specific object with the specific `details` fields.

**Parent Class:**

```
public class Parent {
   @SerializedName("status")
   private String status;

   @SerializedName("date")
   private String date;

   //getter setters...
}
```

**First Child Class**:

```
public class FirstChild extends Parent {
   @SerializedName("specific_1")
   private String specific1;

   @SerializedName("specific_2")
   private String specific2;

  //getter setters...
}
```

**Second Child Class**:

```
public class SecondChild extends Parent {
   @SerializedName("specific_3")
   private String specific3;

   @SerializedName("specific_4")
   private String specific4;

  //getter setters...
}
```

Both child will inherit the `status` and `date` without specifying it on each object. My problem is that `AutoValue` does not support this. What can be the workaround without declaring all of the generic fields on each object?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: No, and from what I understand more on AutoValue, it is not built for this, its purpose is to create an immutable final object which is good for transfering data. I just create multiple objects that includes both status and date (base on my example).

Comment: I'll follow the same. Thanks.